# Visual Studio Code not finding my (local) library file

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp8266

How do I make Visual Studio Code find header files in the lib folder? I have added a `#include <DEV_Config.h>` but it's not finding the file.  The IDE implies it will search all subfolders but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Headers have to be in a subfolder of lib and not directly in the lib folder itself.